# TypeScript, Creating an object from another object with some rules

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with names and dates (timestamp), I need to create another object which holds how many entries with similar dates for last 90 days. Something like this as input and output:

Original available Array of Objects:
(example, in the date of "1627865683" we have only two entries, so two counts as value for that date. and on "1627942449" only one count. Please note the object keys must start from 1 and increment to 90 which are the days when we run our function. We only count the entries for each day within last 90 days. And the values are the count for that day.

```
[
  {name: "Joe", date: 1627865683}
  {name: "John", date: 1627942449}
  {name: "James", date: 1627865683}
   ...............
   ...............
]
```

to

```
[
  { 1: 2 }
  { 2: 1 }
  { 3: 0 }
  { 4: 5 }
  { 5: 10 }
  ....
  ...
  { 90: 1 }
]
```

How do I do it so I don't loop over the initial object multiple times?

Comment: Where do the keys (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 90) come from? And separately, how have you tried to solve the problem? What have you found in your [searching](/help/searching)? There are **dozens** if not hundreds of questions about grouping data that already have answers.

Comment: The goal is to get a count for entries on last 90 days. I will post some of the attempts I have had. The way I can think of is to loop on the array for all counts on day one, then another loop for counts on day two and so on. But I think there should be a smarter way and loop only once but could not figure it out yet.